# Redirect IIS site to work with root domain

Tags: redirects, iis

I have site on IIS in Default Web Site. I want to see my website when I write in browser example.com but now I see my website on address

```
https://example.com/SiteName/Login
```

I did what it says here: Redirect IIS's root to application root

But now when I write

```
https://example.com
```

I see in browser redirection to

```
https://example.com/SiteName/#
```

and next

```
https://example.com/SiteName/Login
```

I would like the name of the SiteName not to appear after entering the address. So when I write

```
https://example.com
```

I want to see

```
https://example.com/Login
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What is the directory structure for the files of your site like?

Comment: Default web site -> MyApplication for Frontend -> react files
 and Default web site -> MyApplication for backend -> .net5 files

Comment: I'am trying to use this [link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/remove-folder-application-names-from-urls/ba-p/2385204) but not works for me. Redirection works but I have "404 - File or directory not found." on example.com/login

Comment: Now I dont know how to share the application under the main link?